# Spring + Hibernate - Tables are not getting created in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, entity

I have configured my web project with Spring and Hibernate. Below is the pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.medosa</groupId>
    <artifactId>MedoSa-backend</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>MedoSa-backend</name>
    <description>A hand for a needed hand</description>

    <properties>
        <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
        <spring.version>4.3.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <jackson.version>1.9.13</jackson.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.3.11.Final</hibernate.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>JBoss repository</id>
            <url>http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate library dependecy start -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jolbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>bonecp</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Hibernate framework -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-validator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-annotations -->
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
        </dependency> -->
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>MedoSa-Backend</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                    <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

and below is my dispatcher-servlet.xml file:

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd">

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.medosa" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:AppConfig.properties" />

<!-- BoneCP configuration -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="${db.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${db.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${db.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${db.password}" />
    <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="60" />
    <property name="idleMaxAge" value="240" />
    <property name="maxConnectionsPerPartition" value="30" />
    <property name="minConnectionsPerPartition" value="10" />
    <property name="partitionCount" value="3" />
    <property name="acquireIncrement" value="5" />
    <property name="statementsCacheSize" value="100" />
    <property name="releaseHelperThreads" value="3" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${db.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven />
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
<bean id="hibernateTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
<bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"
    class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />
```

I have created my model classes. And annotated them with @Entity. I have set hbm2ddl property also to create. Still whenever I am trying to deploy it in the server it is not generating tables. And there is no errors also.

I tried to search all solutions on google, tried many things but didn't work.
will be thankful for your kind help

Comment: There are no entities. Specify `packagesToScan` on your `LocalSessionFactoryBean` to detect the entities.

Comment: Really Thankful ! It worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are not adding the classpath of the model classes. You can add this in your `sessionFactory`.
 After `</property>` tag, add

```
<mapping class="<full class path>"/>
```

For example - `<mapping class="com.hibernate.UserDetails">`

Also, check your Console if SQL statement is being displayed. If Table is getting CREATE and then DROP, Replace

```
<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</prop>
```

with `<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>`
or `<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>`
because

> create-drop: Creates a Schema and then DROP the schema when the SessionFactory is closed explicitly, typically when the application is stopped.
>
> update: Creates the Schema and Updates if there are any changes in Model classes. Its a safer option to use as database doesn't get Deleted or data is not affected on Server Restart.
>
> create: creates the schema, destroying previous data. (Use it only the First time or may result in all data being destroyed the next time you restart your server.

Hope it helps!